# How to use the same Python for Windows and Linux on Windows subsystem for Linux

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Python 3.6 installed on my Windows computer. I installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). When I type `python` into my Ubuntu terminal, I'm told I'm using Python 2.7 (which I imagine comes pre-installed on Ubuntu).

How can I use the same Python for both Windows and Linux, so that if I install a new package with pip from either, I can access it from either? I want the two systems to share the same Python.

It seems as though following something along the lines of [creating an alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699162/using-different-version-of-python) might work, but I'm pretty sure the `pip` command will remain the same (referring to Python 3.6 on Windows and Python 2.7 on Linux), as might other functionality.

Comment: fyi:  Ubuntu comes with both Python & Python3.  The default for most versions is still python 2.7.x (executed with `python`), and to use the python 3.6.x interpreter you use `python3`

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the info! It looks like they're somewhat different though in that on Windows I can just say `pip` and it does Python3 stuff, whereas on Linux, if I do `pip3` it says it's not installed.

Comment: I don't code in python & thus seldom use it.  pip & pip3 are installed on mine (by default I suspect), but I don't use windows/wxl so can't help you further sorry.

Comment: `pip3` indeed may be non default package, in which case you may need to install it via `sudo apt-get install pip3` or `python3-pip`. No on laptop, hence can't suggest the exact package of the top of my mind, bit that's the general form for Python 3 packages in Ubuntu and Debian repositories. In general, I'd suggest familiazing with `apt` utility, as a lot of Python packages on pypi are also available in Ubuntu official repositories.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy If I do that, and I do `pip3 freeze` will I get the same output as doing `pip freeze` on Windows Terminal? I would like to get the same output. I'm fairly familiar with Ubuntu and installing software, I'd just like to make sure I'm not duplicating things and confusing myself :P

Comment: Considering that `pip` on Windows as you say refers to Python 3.6 version and `pip3` on Ubuntu to the same version, it's logical to assume they'll be the same. If you're generating `requirements` file, just beware that on Windows line endings in text files are different than on Linux, hence you may need to use `dos2unix` utility to convert them. Otherwise, I don't think there's any need to worry. Consider checking whether some packages may be Windows-specific also.

Comment: It doesn't look like they're the same at all... Running `Python3` on Ubuntu tells me I'm running Python 3.5. Running `Python` on Windows tells me I'm running Python 3.6. I think they're completely different versions. Still trying to figure out how to use one on the other or merge them in some way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the version of python used in windows by typing in `python.exe` instead of `python3`. This is not recommended and there's no real reason to do so because you'll face several problems with

- CR/LF line endings
- Running python in this way does not preserve the path, hence, say you have `test.py` in the current WSL folder and run `python.exe test.py`. Python will be started in its root directory and will be unable to locate `test.py`

Python behaves identically, like in the case of `pip freeze` e.t.c and will produce the same output if you're running in the same `virtualenv` and hence just using the ubuntu version of python will work fine.

As of 18.04, WSL ubuntu has Python 3.6.5 preinstalled, and you can see both the windows and ubuntu python being used below

[image]

Comment: I did not install python on windows but on Debian/Wsl. How can I use it in vscode windows? It works in `wsl:remote` in vscode. In powershell `wsl python3` works.

Answer (score 2):

I followed these steps. It worked for me. These steps installs python3 on WSL Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

I got help from here - [https://askubuntu.com/a/672836/876942]. Following these steps installs python 2. But then I installed python 3 using [sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip] in last step.

Comment: thanks. this is the only script that worked for me

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?